# Multiple linear regression modelling with discrete dependent and continuous independent variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

Having only very limited knowledge about modelling, I am trying to make models out of independent continuous variables `PARAM_*` to describe each of the discrete dependent `Grp_*`.

The goal would be then to compare these models on new data to classify them.

```
> my_training_df
 GRPS PARAM_1   PARAM_2   PARAM_3   PARAM_4
Grp_A    2.20     -2.17      4.53     -0.39
Grp_A    0.30      3.29      3.98      3.38
Grp_A   -2.33     -0.43      3.45      1.64
Grp_A    4.59     -1.92      0.83     -0.87
Grp_B   -2.85      1.52      1.61     -0.28
Grp_B   -0.31      2.47     -2.23     -2.47
Grp_B    4.03      0.49     -2.16     -0.42
Grp_C    0.50      2.04      1.03      1.33
Grp_C    1.80      4.40      2.20      2.12
Grp_C    4.19      4.55      0.12     -2.91
Grp_C    3.69     -1.88      1.56      2.73
Grp_C   -1.02      3.37      4.95      2.96
```

I planned to use a multiple linear regression method (it seemed to be the easiest to start), but can one create dummy variables to convert the **dependent variable** into a continuous one.

I don't see how the model could work:

```
GRPS = a + b1*PARAM_1 + b2*PARAM_2 + b3*PARAM_3 + b4*PARAM_4
```

What kind of method should I use then (possibly with R)?

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression is the answer I guess.
However, how to choose how to split the data frame into a training and testing set (from a qualitative and quantitative POV)?

Comment: cross-validation may be one possibility I guess